# working out angular velocity

Tags: physics

the chain on a chainsaw is driven by a sprocket 8cm in diameter. If the chain is 120cm long and makes one revolution in 0.2sec, what is the angular velocity (in rad/sec) of the sprocket?

I was working with, the sprocket circumference is 25.133cm so it would have to rotate 4.7745 times for every one revolution of the chain (120/25.133). 4.7745 times in 0.2sec so I multiply 4.7745 by 5 to give me 23.8729957 rotations per second would I then multiply by 360 to get degrees and then convert to radians?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Please ask physics related questions on Physics Stack Exchange. Thanks

Comment: @Algebrology  You can suggest this site without being so abrupt. This question is about cinematics which was long ago a branch of mathematics... :)

Comment: @JeanMarie, I am sorry, If I sounded abrupt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calculation is very simple and you don't need too many intermediate results. Consider a single point in the chain. It moves at constant a velocity of
$$
v = \frac{120~\text{m}/\text{s}}{0.2~\text{s}} = 600~\text{cm}/\text{s}
$$
This is also the velocity of a point moving along the circle. Another way to calculate the velocity of a point moving in a circle is
$$
v = \omega r
$$
and therefore
$$
\omega = \frac{v}{r} = \frac{600~\text{cm}/\text{s}}{4~\text{cm}} = 150~\text{rad}/\text{s}
$$

Comment: Thank you Matti